# Jquery + Instant Search / Filter of a list

Tags: web-part, javascript, jquery, list-view, fast-search

I've seen a clip on bentedder.com where this developer got instant search (filter) to work within a webpart list view. I find this may be very useful for general 911/411 annoucements and archive if i need to quickly find a item reference.

I looked through the tutorial, seemed straight forward, but then saw the video and startec scratching my head...

I noticed the code in his video and tutorial steps with the code are different. I went in and tried, and got no where... I got the search box to appear but it didnt filter anything :( . I'm curious if im missing something alltogether, not understanding 'webpartid's etc.

Link to tutorial & Video clip:
http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-jquery-sharepoint-instant-searchfilter/

(btw, i cant find this referenced by any other blog or someone reposting and tweaking etc)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you need to ensure that your jquery is loaded and be careful about the id of your webpart (or refine your selectors).

It's a really neat and nice solution and there are alternatives based on the same context

eg : https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-get-started-with-jquery-part-4.aspx

In that exemple the author is targeting the generic class applied to a list view webpart

```
var list = $("table.ms-listviewtable");
```

so you don't have to look for a specific id (# in Ben's code).

Comment: got it to work, stupid webpart id was wrong lol. I like that exampleFrancois, i am going to explore that as well :)

Comment: good to hear that your problem is solved. Thanks for the follow-up